# Bridging the gap between the Fisher Yates shuffle and mine

Tags: java, arrays

I'm programming card and deck classes for a school assignment, and my shuffling method isn't consistently passing the test code for it. We are supposed to be using online resources specifically instead of grader/instructor support for this one, and I quickly found the Fisher Yates shuffle method, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the details of it. I'd like to incorporate some of what I came up with and some of it seems pretty similar. Can anyone explain what I'm missing and what it does? Here's my method:

```
public void shuffle() {
     /**
     * I'm trying an orginial idea for the shuffle method of taking the
     * element at each index and switching it out with another element
     * at a random index
     */
    Card placeHolder;
    int i;
    for (int c = 0; c < cardNum; c++) {
        i = (int) (Math.random() * (cardNum-1));
        placeHolder = deckList[i];
        deckList[i] = deckList[c];
        deckList[c] = placeHolder;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an implementation of the Fisher Yates shuffle method. Is your question how does this method work? If so, the comments in the code are the same as the steps in the [Fisher and Yates' original method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Fisher_and_Yates'_original_method). Or something else?

Comment: My question is: is there a part of the FY shuffle method that I'm missing, and what does that part do?

Comment: Have you tried running the code on sample data and inspect the results? I assume you have since you said it isn't passing test code, with  a good debugger you could step through the code line-by-line and see the results of each line in the code and deduce what the code is doing. Even without running the code it's pretty clear what the code does: for all cards in the deck, it "generates a random permutation of the numbers 1 through N" as in the steps 1-5 from the link I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: If you compare some implementations online, it seems like your code has got all the parts (aside from the `int[] array` passed-in parameter) (see https://github.com/jtryan/fys/blob/master/src/Shuffle.java#L18, and https://github.com/ejerson/fisher-yates/blob/master/src/edu/cnm/deepdive/algorithms/Shuffle.java#L75). If you're still unsure why it doesn't pass the test code, a standard IDE debugger (or even just the built-in java debugger [jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)) should be able to see into why the code isn't passing the test cases.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately my code is passing 10499-10502 out of 10506 tests that shuffle the 52 card deck 5000 times to see if each position has a equal likelihood of being shuffled and I don't think I have the patience to wade through that many tests to find the failing instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close.  I'd recommend changing this:

```
i = (int) (Math.random() * (cardNum-1));
```

To this:

```
i = (int) (Math.random() * (cardNum - i) + i);
```

Or use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(origin, bound)` (assuming you are on 1.7 or greater).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That makes sense as shuffling isn't about generating a random order for a sequence, it's about reorganizing a sequence, and my method would allow for a card to be switched back to its original position, which fails a test looking for cards to be in a new position. Thanks again.